# Convert the example date format to required format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I ma getting a response from a Logistic partner like `2013-03-28T13:15:00+05:30` I want this in IST format date. How do i convert it properly.

```
$addTime = explode('+',$response->TrackDetails->ActualDeliveryTimestamp);
if($addTime[1] == '05:30'){
$time = '';
$time = strtotime('+5:30 hrs',$addTime[0]); 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($addTime[0]));
}
```

I tried the above code. but does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$addTime = explode('+','2013-03-28T13:15:00+05:30');
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $addTime[1]);

$dt = new DateTime($addTime[0]);
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT'.intval($hours).'H'));
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT'.intval($minutes).'M'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/SJ2db)

**EDIT**

This is more accurate although the results isn't what you'd expect because of daylight savings time:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2013-03-28T13:15:00+05:30');
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/6nTdo)

Comment: That date is in GMT format. I want it in IST so i need it added with  5:30 hrs